# How to delete info from a connected device on mac even system information?

Tags: system-information, firewire

I connected today my Book studio for the 1st time and my mac crashed when creating a backup with Time machine.

As a consequence I would like to delete the info that this external hard drive ever connected to the Mac. For instance, I see it in Time Machine preferences as a backup destination.

I can see that I connect My WD Book studio in the system information under hardware /firewire/firewire800/Book 1

Is there a way to do that? System information gave you the info about the device but not any way to edit it, or in my case delete it.

**Thanks for your help. Problem resolved.**

Comment: what and where do you see? You could use the AppCleaner app (that I use) to remove all associations.

Comment: or if you know the app name (file name) you could use terminal to find and delete them "mdfind NAME"

Comment: Hi Buscar, in terms of what I can see, I can see that I connect My WD Book studio in the system information under hardware /firewire/firewire800/Book 1.

Comment: I did not use any app so not sure how your comment will apply.

Comment: then trash the syst pref file and have it recreate.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Devices only appear in System Information while they are connected. Therefore, it's unclear what information you are trying to remove exactly, and from where.

Comment: #tubedogg yes deices only appear in system information when connected. In windows there is a places where you can delete the info that a device was ever connected to the laptop. I am trying to find a way to do the same on mac. I am just not sure where to start and how to do it. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

By any chance do you mean delete **everything** on the MyBook Studio drive?

If so open Disk Utility, select the drive in the left-hand pane and then click the "Erase" tab, select the format you want (best bet: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)) and click erase.

Everything (and I mean everything) on that drive will vanish in a cloud of unseen bytes.

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for you comment. No i just meant delete the info on the mac that that external hard drive was ever connected to it.

Comment: This is what I thought the person meant. I'm upvoting it since 95% of the people that come to the site with this question will likely want this answer as opposed to the "clean up one".

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all history is hard. There are log files, backup logs, stored spotlight hooks to identify that disk's "fingerprint" so that Time Machine can know it's connected again. There can be thousands of drives named the same as your drive, but you Mac will only back up to that drive (or one with the same randomly generated ID).

In practice, just open Time Machine preferences and turn off that backup drive / delete it as a destination.

The interface to do this has changed in recent OS X versions, so use the built in help for specific guidance. If you want to ask a follow on question with a screen shot / details about your OS level and version, someone can assist further.